# Why stack overflow error with this Scala code?

Tags: scala, stack-overflow

I wrote some awkward Fibonacci implementation just to test out Stream

```
def fibonacci(a : Int, b : Int) : Stream[Int] = Stream(a, b) ++ fibonacci(a + b, a + b * 2)
```

I know this is not the best implementation but couldn't figure out why this would stack overflow on any call to it, say `fibonacci(0, 1) take(1)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you force the evaluation to the recursive `fibonacci` call immediately.

In other words you need to create a lazy generator instead, either by using a method such as [continually](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$) or by mapping on the tail. Scaladoc actually have a good example for how to create a fibonacci stream here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream

Comment: How do I force the evaluation to `fibonacci` immediately? Instead why `def fibonacci(first : Int, second : Int) : Stream[Int] = first #:: fibonacci(second, first + second)` works?

Comment: Whenever you call a function it gets evaluated immediately. So in your example you are calling the ``fibonacci`` method which will immediately call the ``fibonacci`` method which will immediately ... And so on. If you instead used the ``continually`` method to create the stream you would only do recursive methods when you needed. So, when the ``take`` in your example is called, your stream will calculate the needed values (1).

Comment: As for the other example, ``#::`` is like the `::` (cons) operator for lists, but that uses lazy evaluation ([see the ``=>`` in the constructor argument](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$ConsWrapper) - just like in the ``continually`` method). Meaning, that the next call to fibonacci will only evaluate when needed, just as it happens with ``continually``.

Comment: I would say `++` forces the evaluation of the recursive call, as the argument is by value. Which is quite unfortunate for streams, but it looks like it comes with inheritance in the collection library.